# Sort strings with custom order in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, string, oracle, sorting

**Problem**:

We first define a custom character order in the following way:

```
A < ... < Z  <  a < ... < z  <  0 < ... < 9  <                              <
capitals        lowercase       digits         printable special characters   space
```

Special characters' order is not specified, so, they can be compared arbitrarily.

Given a table `INPUT` with one `VARCHAR2` column, sort its content (strings containing only characters listed in order definition) in lexicographic order, using the character order defined above.

**Question:** how can one implement such sorting in pure Oracle SQL (without using PL/SQL and undocumented functions)?

It looks like Oracle DB doesn't have a feature to use such an order directly in `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Are all the strings in the `INPUT` column composed entirely of ASCII characters, or do we need to ask you how you want to sort accented characters, multi-byte characters, etc.? (Not sure if there is a satisfactory solution either way, but it helps to have a precise problem statement to think about.)

Comment: What do you mean by "printable special characters"? Only ASCII ones, or all Unidoce ones?

Comment: @mathguy, consider only ASCII characters, including "printable special" ones from the problem statement.

Comment: OK. The order you requested is an example of a **collation** - a specification for linguisting sorting (ordering) of strings. Oracle supports ordering according to a specific collation, and it supports collations for many natural languages. What you are requesting is a custom collation. Oracle supports customizing collations. How to do that is probably too much for the type of questions asked on this forum; did you take a look at the documentation?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `translate()`:

```
order by translate(col, 
                   'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789',
                   '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
                  )
```

This replaces the characters that you care about with the "natural" ASCII ordering of the characters.

Comment: This still won't help with the non-alphanumeric characters, which are all over the map in the ASCII encoding. Of course, `translate` can be modified to accommodate that as well, but it becomes a lot messier. And don't forget that the OP wants `space` to come last.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a collation at the column level. Collations specify how `VARCHAR2` values are compared and sorted.

See [Column Level Collation](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/column-level-collation-and-case-insensitive-database-12cr2#column-level) or [Statement Level Collation](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/column-level-collation-and-case-insensitive-database-12cr2#column-level).

Comment: LOL - we were writing about the same thing and at the same time. Note though that the collation the OP requested is not simply "German" or "Italian" - he will need to build his own, custom one.

Comment: @mathguy I hear you. It seems it's not easy to create a custom collation in Oracle.

Comment: I wondered about that myself several times in the past, but I didn't have the motivation to follow through. I just looked through the documentation right now, see for example https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NLSPG/ch12custlocale.htm#GUID-201607DC-224F-4A2C-9935-69110F8BDEE2. Apparently there is a utility to, for example, customize collations, the Locale Builder; I was able to start it easily following the instructions given in the documentation. It may not be too difficult, but it's certainly not trivial either.